# Problems with pickle and encodings

Tags: python, encoding, pickle

I am working with sizeable set of text files. Many of them written in different encodings. I create list of objects which contains some of the substrings from those text files. I am taking care of encoding problems when opening the files (objects are created correctly and could be used).
Here is my list:

```
len(hands)
47580
type(hands)
<class 'list'>
type(hands[0])
<class '__main__.BridgeHand'>
```

Now I try to pickle this object:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(hands, open("handspi.p", "wb"))
```

It creates 9MB file handspi.
The problems start when I try to unpickle it:

```
hh = pickle.load(open(#some path to this pickle file))
```

Stack trace ends with:

```
File "C:\Python31\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 30: character maps to      <undefined>
```

What do I do about it ?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: You did not show the exact line of code that actually triggers the error -- it's always a good idea to do so.  Probably, your are not opening the file in binary mode (`"rb"`), but I can only guess.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That solves the problem, I am retarded :(

Comment: Sven did answer, but I formalised it and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to try opening the file in binary mode as you are currently reading it as an ascii file.

```
open('picklefile.pkl','rb')
```

Comment: Yeah, I copy pasted from python wiki (http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) where "rb" wasn't used. I guess the reason is that I am on windows :(